# EditText does not get rounded

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am trying to get a rounded EditText.

My EditText in layout is like

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_round"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
</FrameLayout>
```

and the drawable I am using as EditText background is like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:padding="10dp"
 android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:topRightRadius="12dp" />

</shape>
```

In my XML graphical layout, my edittext looks fine and rounded, but in emulator and also in device it does not look like that?

Does anyone have any idea why could that be?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have the `android:padding="10dp"` attribute in the `<shape...>` tag? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: deleted the "android:padding" tag, still there is no improvement.also it is not helpful to put a google link.as I said in the graphical design section of xml, edittext looks fine and rounded

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `android:padding="10dp"` attribute to make the drawable look like this. I just tested it and removing the padding attribute shows the rounded corners just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topRightRadius="12dp" />

</shape>
```

To add `padding` to the `Shape Drawable`, notice the padding attribute added in the code above.

*The proof lies in the pudding: ;-)*

**Device Screenshot:**

[image]

**Emulator Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: did you tested in device or emulator? because it looks fine on the xml but when I run it, it's still not working.

Comment: @FatihKaplan: Uploading the screenshot in like 5 seconds.

Comment: @FatihKaplan: This is on a device.

Comment: I see it is working but nothing changed in my device.can it be because of the sdk?

Comment: @FatihKaplan: To the best of my knowledge, it works right from 1.6 API to the current API. The only issue I am aware of is when setting corners on just one side of the Shape. The app the screenshots are from support right from 2.1 to 4.2 without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the `stroke` element, so you probably just don't see the background (since it's only a white fill!). When you change the background or add a stroke, it should be visible.

Add:

```
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />
```

And poof! The rectangle is visible :) BTW The padding isn't the issue - it's simply ignored.

Comment: I have added [stroke] element but still nothing changed.As I said it looks fine on XML it just does not work on device.

Comment: hm. what device are you running? what Android version? it matters since some features were available later and some - sooner. also, do you interact with the `EditText` from the code in any way?

Comment: I am very very sorry for busying everyone now I checked and I saw that I am changing background also from code.Thanks everyone for helping.